# What is wrong with the cast at second line?

Tags: java

```
Object arr = new int[]{1,2,3};
arr = (int[])arr; 

int someArr [] = (int[])arr;

for(int i:arr)  // compilation error
     System.out.println(i);

for(int i:someArr) //works fine
     System.out.println(i);
```

Why the cast at second line doesn't convert arr to an int array? I get a compilation error at line 4 which says "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of `java.lang.Iterable`". While debugging, at line 2, the variable snapshot shows arr with indexed values.

Comment: Because `arr` is statically typed as an Object, and you therefore can't natively iterate over it. Use `for(int i:someArr )`.

Comment: There is no direct way to do this. You have to cast each and every element manually.

Comment: Just a side note: it's consider better coding style to write `int[] someArr`. After all it's an array of `int` not an array of `someArr`

Comment: if you could change the data type of the receiving var (left hand side) then why bother with types at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement `arr = (int []) arr` first tries to cast the value stored in `arr` to an `int []`. Then, in order to be able to do the assignment, it tries to cast the result of the right-hand side of `=` to the type of the variable on the left-hand side. Since the type of the variable on the left-hand side is `Object` the `int []` is casted back to `Object`. So `arr` stays `Object`.

What do we learn from that? You cannot change the declared type of a variable. Never. In particular, you cannot do it by assigning anything of another type to it. Either the assignment works and the assigned value is casted to the declared type of the variable, or the assignment fails. The type of the variable does never change.

Answer (score 1):

Casting only works in line in which it is used. In the next line the compiler will forget about it, and only see the definition of `arr`, which is still `Object`. If you don't wan't to create a new variable, you can add casting in places in which you need to tell the compiler what to do.

```
Object arr = new int[]{1,2,3};

for(int i : (int[])arr) // cast when using the object
    System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can only iterate over an array or an instance of `java.lang.Iterable`.

This refers to the compile-time (i.e. static) rather than runtime (i.e. dynamic) type.

`arr`'s compile-time is `Object`, which means you can't iterate over it, *irrespective of what its runtime type might be*.

Answer (score 1):

The declared type of `arr` being `Object`, the compiler is not sure it refers to an array, and hence doesn't know how to iterate over it.

> Why the cast at second line doesn't convert arr to an int array?

For reference types (such as `Object`), a cast doesn't convert, but merely checks that the reference points to an object of the given type. If that check suceeds, you can then use all features of that type (if the cast doesn't succeed, a ClassCastException is thrown).

Answer (score 1):

Because You are doing the Down Casting. In the Down casting you have to do Explicit Casting from Object to Int . 
You are doing. Like this

> for(int i:someArr)
>   //It's work fine.

So you have to Explicit cast this arr to int.

In Up Casting you have not do Explicit Casting. It's defaultly provided Implicit Casting.

> for(Object i=somearr)

Here, Object is the super class of the all the classes.

You got my point?

Answer (score 0):

arr is an `Object`.`Java` cannot magically `cast` like that.

```
for(int i:someArr )  // compile
                 System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your casting won't change the **type** of `arr`. `arr` type is still `Object` as you declared, and you can't iterate over `Object`.